# Passing a unique session ID to Winston logger

Tags: session, winston, morgan

I am trying to figure out if there is a way to use a unique (per request) session ID in all of the winston logger calls when an HTTP request is made.

Elaboration on the issue:

Given a scenario that several hundred requests hit a website per minute and each request passes through different functions which log out various messages.

My goal is to log messages including a unique session ID per request using [winston](https://www.npmjs.com/package/winston) logger, until the response is sent.

I generate a unique session ID for the request using `app.use(session(...))` from **express-session** library.

Using **morgan**, the HTTP logs are printed with a unique session ID like so:

```
logger = winston.createLogger(...);

const myStream = {
  write: (text: string) => {
    logger.info(text);
  }
}

morgan.token('sessionid', function (req, res) { return req['sessionID'] });
app.use(morgan(':remote-addr - :remote-user [:date[clf]] ":method :url HTTP/:http-version" :status :res[content-length] ":referrer" ":user-agent"  ["SESSION_ID :sessionid"]', { stream: myStream }));
```

However, I also want to use the same session ID in other logger.* functions elsewhere in the code. I am able to do that but as the number of simulataneous requests (using k6 load test) increases, the session ID gets overwritten by a new session ID of another request.

My code for using the session ID in request in a winston transport is:

```
public static initializeLogger(appInstance: express.Application) {

        if (!appInstance) throw new Error(`Cannot initialize logger. Invalid express.Application instance passed. Logging may not be available`);
        
        appInstance.use((req, res, next) => {
            //this.m_sessionID = req["sessionID"];
            this.m_logger.clear();
            this.m_logger = winston.createLogger({
                level: LOG_LEVEL,
                levels: winston.config.syslog.levels,
                format: winston.format.json(),
                transports: [
                    new winston.transports.Console({ format: winston.format.simple() }),
                    new winston.transports.File({ filename: 'error.log', level: 'error' }),
                    new winston.transports.File({ filename: 'debug.log', level: 'debug' }),
                    new WinstonCloudWatch({
                        logGroupName: CLOUDWATCH_LOG_GROUP_NAME,
                        logStreamName: function () {
                            let date = new Date().toISOString().split('T')[0];
                            return 'k-server-logs-' + date;
                        },
                        awsRegion: AWS_REGION,
                        awsAccessKeyId: process.env.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID,
                        awsSecretKey: process.env.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY,
                        retentionInDays: process.env.CLOUDWATCH_LOG_RETENTION_DAYS ? Number(process.env.CLOUDWATCH_LOG_RETENTION_DAYS) : 30,
                        messageFormatter: (log) => {
                            return `${JSON.stringify({
                                message: log.message,
                                sessionID: req["sessionID"],
                                level: log.level
                            })}`
                        }
                    })
                ],
            });
            next();
        });
    }
```

I was hoping putting the winston logger in `app.use(...)` middleware would set up the cloudwatch transport for the winston logger along with using the req.sessionID as each request comes in.

However, this setup isn't working. If I send even 10 simultaneous requests, this code breaks and the sessionID is incorrectly stamped on logger.* messages and/or duplicated across multiple messages.

I reviewed other implementations such as https://solidgeargroup.com/en/express-logging-global-unique-request-identificator-nodejs/ but could not get it to work.

Hoping for some advice - I am sure my setup is off.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Key hint from  [https://solidgeargroup.com/en/express-logging-global-unique-request-identificator-nodejs/](http://%20https://solidgeargroup.com/en/express-logging-global-unique-request-identificator-nodejs/)

Use express-http-context which has a set and get function that will ensure that the unique session ID is available throughout your code.

```
import httpContext from 'express-http-context';
...
...
logger.add(new WinstonCloudWatch({
                level:LOG_LEVEL,
                logGroupName: CLOUDWATCH_LOG_GROUP_NAME,
                logStreamName: function () {
                    let date = new Date().toISOString().split('T')[0];
                    return `${process.env.CLOUDWATCH_LOG_FILE_NAMEPREFIX}-logs-${date}`;
                },
                awsRegion: AWS_REGION,
                awsAccessKeyId: process.env.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID,
                awsSecretKey: process.env.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY,
                retentionInDays: process.env.CLOUDWATCH_LOG_RETENTION_DAYS ? Number(process.env.CLOUDWATCH_LOG_RETENTION_DAYS) : 30,
                messageFormatter: (log) => {
                    return `${JSON.stringify({
                        message: log.message,
                        **sessionID: httpContext.get('reqId')**,
                        level: log.level
                    })}`
                }
}));
```